# Suspected Memory Leak causing Arch Linux with Gnome DE freeze and lockup

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, memory, freeze

I need some help in regards of how I should solve this long standing problem. Arch linux with both `lts` and rolling kernel installed and updated to their respective latest version. DE is Gnome. Always locks up and freezes after certain amount of time during a large file transfer or a sustained constant write to a drive. Eg, downloading or copying files.

I had a guess at this being a memory leak problem, and so transparent hugepages came up to me as something I should disable to see if the situation improves.
I did it as instructed https://blog.nelhage.com/post/transparent-hugepages/:

It feels like as if there is less occurrence of it, but it still happens nonetheless.
Specifics:

```
echo madvise | sudo tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

And then added `transparent_hugepage=madvise` to `/etc/default/grub`, then regenerated GRUB config.

Sometimes I might be able to to `ctrl + alt + F2` then it switches to tty2, switch back to tty1, I am met with the log in screen, log in with all work closed and system seems fine again. But even that does not work every time. I would like to eliminate this locking up completely in the future.

To add more info, writing without reading from it like during a download causes this, reading files without writing is fine.

Hardware is:

```
i7 6700k
Nvidia 980ti
Maximus Ranger Viii
Intel SSD
WD Elements 10TB external drive via USB
```

Please let me know what are your thoughts, would this be a memory leak problem causing the DE to lock up and freeze? What would be a way to prevent this?

I do not know which log post or error I should look into for this, if you can point that out, is also appreciated.

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Are you sure it freezes? Have you tried pinging it, trying to use `ssh`. Unless you have some error to attach to the freezing, it could be just about anything, likely hardware related. Do you have some error message, does anything seem off in the logs? (Check *kern.log* after the reboot, it might have some info).

Comment: I do not have ssh on the machine, and it does not respond to any mouse clock, what do you mean by pinging? And I cannot seem to find an error in logs, or it is that I don't know where to find it.

Comment: By pinging I mean doing `ping host` from another host.

Comment: I do not think i would be able to do that, don't want to set that up in my computer. And also, which log would you suggest me to take a look at? Maybe the nvidia related ones or could you point me to the path?

Comment: `/var/log/kern.log`

Comment: That log is not in the place. I can't find it.